# Poisson regression with both response and explanatory variables as counting

Tags: r, glm

I’ve got the following variables:

Response: number of quota units leased (in and out) by fishers.

Explanatory: number of quota units own by fishers.

I fitted a GLM (Poisson), but I’m not totally sure if it’s right, considering that the explanatory variable is count as well. I’ve found examples of Poisson regression just with categorical and continuous explanatory variables, but not with counting variables.

So:

1. Am I right using Poisson with my data? If not so, what alternative do I have?
2. The residuals variances of my model are not homogeneous. I understand that Poisson regression allows face this problem, or should I pay attention to this issue and solve it (using weights, for example)?

Any help would much appreciated,

Comment: This question is more suited to c[rossvalidated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/). I have flagged it to be migrated, so sit back and wait.

Comment: No Don't repost the question. This question will be migrated (just be patient)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem seems like it could be well modeled with Poisson regression. The residual variance should NOT be "homogeneous". The Poisson model assumes that the variance is proportional to the mean. You have options if that asumption is violated. The quasi-biniomial and the negative binomial models can also be used and they allow some relaxation of the dispersion parameter estimates.

If the number of quota units owned by fishers sets an upper bound on the number used then I would not think that should be used as an explanatory variable, but might better be entered as offset=log(quota_units). It will change the interpretation of the estimates, such that they are estimates of the log(usage_rate).

Comment: Hi,thanks a lot for you feedback.Advice. I'll also explore the alternatives. thanks again, Rafael